# How to use radio buttons in react boostrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

How can I do so that the radio buttons are selected depending on the click that is given to each button. because when I click on elguno of the two radio buttons they are not selected.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    valuesQuestions: 1,
})

const handleChange = (event) => setState({
    ...state,
    valuesQuestions: event.currentTarget.value
});


<Form>
   <Form.Group className="mb-3">
    <Form.Label>¿Dolor de garganta?</Form.Label>
      <div className="btn-check selects--radio">
         </div>
           </Form.Group>
            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" value={state.valuesQuestions} default={1} onChange={handleChange}>
                        <ToggleButton value={1} variant="outline-warning" >Si</ToggleButton>
                        <ToggleButton value={2} variant="outline-warning"  >No</ToggleButton>
                    </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-group-props) , `handleChange` returns array of toggled value.  So in `useState` you must initial an array of default values.

If you want to have initial state:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([1])
```

And if you don't want initial:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([])
```

So:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([1]);

const handleChange = (val) => setState(val);

<Form>
    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Label>¿Dolor de garganta?</Form.Label>
        <div className="btn-check selects--radio">
        </div>
    </Form.Group>
    <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" defaultValue={state.valuesQuestions} onChange={handleChange}>
        <ToggleButton value={1} variant="outline-warning" >Si</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={2} variant="outline-warning"  >No</ToggleButton>
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
</Form>
```

Comment: is that I do not want it to have a default value, what I want is for it to remain selected in the option where I click

Comment: @AndresMendez I updated the answer. try it again

Comment: still not working

Comment: add your code in a sandbox

Comment: In codesanbox it works but in my component it does not and I am using the same code from there, what could it be?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, which was that I was missing the id = "tbg-btn-1" and id = "tbg-btn-2" to the selectors

Comment: So, have problem yet? @AndresMendez

Comment: my problem is solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `event.currentTarget.value` by `event`:

```
const handleChange = (event) => setState({
    ...state,
    valuesQuestions: event
});
```

Comment: still not working